# broken chain after upgrade: FATAL: Unable to initialize the API: -32603: Unknown error occurred:

Tags: substrate

we are building a network based on parity substrate.

when upgrading a network through sudo / setCode, which previously worked like a charm many times, we end up with a broken chain when uploading a new runtime based on substrate 2.0.1 into a chain based on substrate 2.0.0.

the error we get after an upgrade is:
`FATAL: Unable to initialize the API: -32603: Unknown error occurred: Client, VersionInvalid, Other, \"Instantiation: Export ext_default_child_storage_storage_kill_version_2 not found\`

we already checked for additional code rendering the new build defect, but separately, both builds work flawless.

as the newer chainspec contains more details for the contracts pallet, and multiaddress format, it seems there are some changes, which the old runtime cannot chew, but coming from the error, we cannot identify, what the original problem is and could not find any documentation explaining eventually breaking changes for a patch version bump.

changing the genesis chainspec renders the following builds incompatible with the old runtime, therefore a chain cannot be upgraded if we change the chainspec.

but prior to the recent updates, the build never complained about missing data in the spec, therefore the question is, where is this introduced or how can we disable this or is it a breaking change we oversaw.

thanks in advance for any pointers.

Comment: Did you increment the `spec_version` ? [here](https://substrate.dev/rustdocs/v2.0.0/frame_system/struct.LastRuntimeUpgradeInfo.html#structfield.spec_version) is the docs on proper use, and if you used the template, [here](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/571448fb41388d2f4b1859fd3922ef623c3dcce6/runtime/src/lib.rs#L94-L102) is where it's set.

Comment: Also I am sure you have looked at [the runtime upgrage docs](https://substrate.dev/docs/en/knowledgebase/runtime/upgrades#storage-migrations) recently - I am not sure if there is help for this error code in there expressly, but might help.

Comment: yes, thanks, we did quite some onchain upgrades in the past, had in total over 4M blocks produced. for some reason when upgrading the pallets etc to the current version, compiling works, but you cannot run the node if you dont change the chainspec to meet some more parameters, which breaks the genesis it seems.

Comment: "this error indicates that they have done a runtime upgrade, without updating the node before.This is a new host function" was the word I got when asked internally. So it seems that you need to update the node first, then perform a runtime upgrade. Otherwise it looks like this might be a bug we should post to the repo as an issue: github.com/paritytech/substrate
Would you mind starting one there on this IF you find the node upgrade -> runtime upgrade doesn't work? You can tag me (NukeManDan) so I can follow and get further support there.

Comment: thanks a lot for the reply, will catch up on github then.